# Meta elements are not getting closed on XML to HTML Conversion

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am working on to convert the XML to the HTML. In that the Meta elements are not getting closed on the output of Html.

XML Input:

```
<topic>
   <title>Sample</title>
</topic>
```

XSL I'm using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="topic" mode="chapterHead">
    <head>
      <xsl:call-template name="generateCharset"/>   
    </head>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generateCharset">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

HTML Output I'm getting:

```
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
```

Need to close or self-close the Meta element.

Comment: The output I am getting is the text `"Sample"`. That's because your template has a mode. If I remove it, I get a closed `meta` element - that's because your output method is `xml`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B6R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is closed.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) The HTML element is self-closing and has no need for a closing slash and it never has been specified or required to have one. In fact, no HTML element has ever had that requirement.

While placing a closing slash there is allowed for legacy reasons related to XHTML, the slash has no meaning, [does nothing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags) and browsers ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you should not put that `meta` element at all in your HTML result generated by XSLT, instead, if you want to output HTML you should use `<xsl:output method="html"/>` in XSLT and then the XSLT processor on serialization will take care of generating and inserting the `meta` element.